# concatenating float with string resulting in error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do the following in a select statement:
Table A has a column called f_total.
f_total is nvarchar(50) null
The data stored in f_total are integers.  For example. 3500000
I need to divide f_total by 100000000, round it to 3 decimal places, and concatenate "$" before the output and "mm" after the output.
This is what I have in the select:

```
iif(f_total > 0, '$' + cast(round(cast(f_total/100000000 as float),3) as nvarchar(20)),'') +
'mm ' as Text1
```

union
  0 as Text1

Solution: INT in the second part of union takes precedence and that's why the first part of the union forced the conversion to int data type.
change "0 as Text1" to "'0' as Text1" (single quotes around 0)

if f_total = 3500000, output should be $0.035mm

I tried many combinations of casts but keep getting error " conversion failed from nvarchar/varchar to int data type.  There are tons of posts out there but I can't seem to locate an answer that works for this case.

Comment: if f_total is nvarchar, exactly what do you expect will happen when you do `/10000000`? `nvarchar / int` is what's causing your error. It never reaches your cast calls in the first place. why store integers in a varchar field in the first place?

Comment: I have tried cast(round(cast(cast(f_total as float)/100000000.0 as float),3) as varchar(20))....but no luck.  In the error I see the following: error converting the varchar value '0.035mm ' to data type int

Comment: Without seeing your entire query and what data you're actually using in your tables, it's impossible to know for sure. But the error is pretty straight forward. At some point in your query you're trying to convert a varchar value to an integer and it's not working because the varchar value contains letters...

Comment: ZLK- Lets reverse what you said.  I am not trying to convert it to an int.  As a matter of fact, I am trying to figure out at what point it sees something as an int.  What I have shown there is the entire select statement and it is using one table and only one value f_value nvarchar(255).  The "100000000" is hardcoded in.

Comment: if the data type on the column should be changed, i completely agree.  However, I have to find a way to nail this issue right now.  In simplest terms, I just need to divide the f_value (nvarchar(255)) by hundred million, round it to 3 decimal places and put '$' sign before it and "mm" after it.  Hope that helps!!

Comment: Might try checking for numeric, I suspect you will find a cell that isn't an integer as you expect;  iif(IsNumeric(@f_total) = 1 AND @f_total  > 0, '$' + cast(round(cast(@f_total/100000000 as float),3) as nvarchar(20)),'NA') +
'mm ' as Text1

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  It was actually my bad.  There were five queries where this situation arised.  Only one of those 5 had a union.  When I first ran into the issue, I was working with simple query as described in the question.  After some time, I randomly went at it with all combinations in the query w/ union, without realizing that this one has a union.

Comment: It always converted to an int because the same column in the union is defaulted to int.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast f_total to float.

Your query should be like that:

```
iif(f_total > 0, '$' + cast(round(cast(cast(f_total as float)/100000000 
as float),3) as nvarchar(20)),'') +
'mm ' as Text1
```

Output : $0.035

I am sure ,you will be get your desire output .

Thanks .

Comment: Yes, I casted all f_total fields to float and that worked.  Thanks.  My main problem was the second select in the union that contained 0 as a defaulted int.  This was forcing the first select to ALWAYS cast to an int.  I changed the second select default value from int type 0 to literal type '0' and that ultimately fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since 2012 version you can use **[CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)** function :

```
SELECT IIF(f_total > 0, CONCAT('$', CONVERT(FLOAT, f_total)/100000000,'mm'),'')
```

*test:*
[image]

---

for older version than 2012 you can use this:

```
SELECT IIF(f_total > 0, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),CONVERT(FLOAT, f_total)/100000000) + 'mm','')
```

*test:*
[image]